# create dict from two lists python without zip()?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I'm creating a dict using zip(), how would I do it without zipping or numpy?

```
def listtodict(list1, list2):
    return dict(zip(list1, list2))  

print listtodict([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
```

Comment: It's kind of like asking how to drive a nail, but I don't want to use a hammer to do it, even though I have one.  I'm not going to explain why I don't want to use the hammer.

Comment: If you're looking for help with your homework you should say so because these answers aren't what I'd use for homework.

Comment: Yup, if you want a good answer to this, then you are going to need to explain why you don't want to use `zip()`.

Answer (score 7):

Just for fun...

```
def listtodict(list1, list2):
    return dict(max(vars(__builtins__).items())[1](list1, list2))
```

Comment: Love it. Took me a second to work out why you were using `max()`, then I remembered the alphabet. ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> A=[1,2,3,4,5]
>>> B=['a','b','c','d','e']
>>> {A[i]: B[i] for i in range(len(A))}
{1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd', 5: 'e'}
```

Equivalent to:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> for i in range(len(A)):
        d[A[i]] = B[i]


>>> d
{1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd', 5: 'e'}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> dict(map(None,[1,2,3,4,5],['a','b','c','d','e']))
{1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd', 5: 'e'}
```

Comment: haha cheater!!! +1 for being cunning (This doesn't work in Python 3 btw)

Comment: @jamylak I'll run some timeings now, it'll be interesting to compare how fast each one is

Comment: `dict(map(lambda *a:a,[1,2,3,4,5],['a','b','c','d','e']))` for Python3

Answer (score 3):

This version consumes `B`

```
>>> A=[1,2,3,4,5]
>>> B=['a','b','c','d','e']
>>> {k: B.pop(0) for k in A}
{1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd', 5: 'e'}
```

This one leaves `B` intact

```
>>> A=[1,2,3,4,5]
>>> B=['a','b','c','d','e']
>>> iterb = iter(B)
>>> {k: next(iterb) for k in A}
{1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd', 5: 'e'}
```

As a function

```
def listtodict(list1, list2):
    return {k: list2.pop(0) for k in list1}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> A=[1,2,3,4,5]
>>> B=['a','b','c','d','e']
>>> dict((lambda f: (lambda x: x(x))(lambda y: f(lambda *args: y(y)(*args))))(lambda f: lambda a, b, i=0: ((a[i], b[i]),) + f(a, b, i+1) if i < len(a) else ())(A, B))
{1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd', 5: 'e'}
```

Comment: Why didn't I think of that?

Comment: It's just so obvious once you see it.

Comment: I think guido would like this one!

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun...

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> l1 = [0, 1, 2]
>>> l2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> dict(np.array([l1, l2]).T)
{'1': 'b', '0': 'a', '2': 'c'}
```

Comment: There are 2 types of people in this world. Those who use numpy for fun and those who don't.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the least horrific way to do it would be:

```
>>> keys = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> values = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
>>> values_iter = iter(values)
>>> d = {}
>>> for key in keys:
...     d[key] = next(values_iter)
... 
>>> d
{1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd', 5: 'e'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't try this at home...

```
>>> l1 = [0, 1, 2]
>>> l2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> list(csv.DictReader(StringIO(','.join(l2)), l1)).pop()
{0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c'}
```

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of experimentation I think I have come up with a most ***pythonic*** solution, taking advantage of various strengths in the language such as generator experessions and starch overloading.

```
>>> from collections import Counter as potato
>>> from operator import or_ as _and
>>> l1 = [0, 1, 2]
>>> l1, l2 = [0, 1, 2], ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> l = l1 + l2[::-1]
>>> dict(reduce(_and, (potato({l.pop(0): l.pop()}) for i in l1 if l), potato()))
{0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c'}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> A=[1,2,3,4,5]
>>> B=['a','b','c','d','e']
>>> d=defaultdict(B.pop)
>>> itemgetter(*reversed(A))(d)
('e', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'a')
>>> dict(d)
{1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd', 5: 'e'}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> A=[1,2,3,4,5]
>>> B=['a','b','c','d','e']
>>> d={}
>>> [d.setdefault(a, B.pop()) for a in reversed(A)]
['e', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'a']
>>> d
{1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd', 5: 'e'}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def listtodict(list1, list2):
    d = {}
    while list1:
        d[list1.pop()] = list2.pop()
    return d
```